# How can I make <li> tag actived? in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have pagination like this

this is javascript code for my webpage

```
var pagingList = $('<ul>', {class: 'pagination list-unstyled list-inline'});                                                                          

$('.page_container').append($('<div>', {class:"text-center"}).append(pagingList));                                                                    

        if (startPage > 10) {                                                                                                                                 
          var prev_page = $('<li>').append($('<a>', {href: '/bjcam/' + boardname + '/' + (startPage - 1)}).text('prev'));                                     
          pagingList.append(prev_page);                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                                     
        for (var i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++) {                                                                                                          
          if (i > maxPage) break;                                                                                                                             
          var current_page = $('<li>').append($('<a>', {href: '/bjcam/' + boardname + '/' + i}).text(i));                                                     
          pagingList.append(current_page);                                                                                                                    
        }                                                                                                                                                     
        if (maxPage > endPage) {                                                                                                                              
          var next_page = $('<li>').append($('<a>', {href: '/bjcam/' + boardname + '/' + (startPage + 10)}).text('next'));                                    
          pagingList.append(next_page);                                                                                                                       
        }
```

I want to make `<li>` actived when this paginations is clicked
Now, below is my code I'm trying to do

```
$('.pagination li').click(function() {                                                                                                                
          $('.pagination li').addClass("active")                                                                                                              
        })
```

How can I make `<li> tag actived` when it is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.pagination li').click(function(e) {
    $('.navbar li.active').removeClass('active');
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Try like this...

Comment: Side note, addClass will not double add the class, so technically you could do without the hasClass check.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your click event `(when clicking upon li)` add this code.

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```